# How to merge Oracle data

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

There are two schemas in Oracle11g. For example db1 and db2.

They have same structure of tables and different data to each other.

Now I want to merge data on db1 with data on db2 with no duplication.

But I can’t, duplication is happened.

I tried two different ways like bellow:

1. Import from dumpFile.db1 into db1 then import from dumpFile.db2 into db1.
2. After import data into both schemas and executo direct path insert.

   insert/*+ APPEND */ into db1.myTable (SELECT * FROM db2,myTable);.

Are there good way to merge without duplication?

Comment: Doesn't the Oracle `MERGE` statement work for you?

Comment: Actually I want merge any schema without ON condition or WHERE condition.
I mean unless I know about table structure especially what primary key is, I want merge them if they have same structure.
But As Leigh Riffel answered bellow ,I have to know about fields in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use impdp command with CONTENT=DATA_ONLY DATA_OPTIONS=SKIP_CONSTRAINT_ERRORS .
It seems no duplication.

Comment: duplication is avoided by the primary/unique key contraints. so a record is a duplicate of another record of the same table exactly if they have the same value for the primary key or at least one unique key. that seems to be a reasonable definition if no surrogate keys are used.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a WHERE clause to your select that eliminates the duplicates:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO db1.myTable (
   SELECT * FROM db2.myTable b WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 FROM db1.myTable a WHERE a.ID = b.ID)
   );
```

If you don't have a field like ID that is unique across the two tables, then you will need to compare more fields, perhaps all of them.

Comment: Sounds good.I'll try it.